# Dice Roller Simulator using arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, dice

I am trying to create a program that will ask the user to input the number of 6 sided dice to be rolled and then how many rolls(trials) they want to run.  At the end of the code it should display to the user how many of each number possible there are and if there was a streak(if there was it should say what the streak was and at what roll number it started.

To keep it simple thus far my program should only ask how many trials to run with two 6 sided dice and show the displays as listed above.

The issue is that the display is not showing the percentages as my math should allow and when it comes to the streak I have no idea how to state which trial it started at and what number was on the streak.... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class RollThoseDice {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //start of method

    //variables needed for program
    int total;
    int newStreak = 1;
    int streak = 1;
    int totalIs2 = 0;
    int totalIs3 = 0;
    int totalIs4 = 0;
    int totalIs5 = 0;
    int totalIs6 = 0;
    int totalIs7 = 0;
    int totalIs8 = 0;
    int totalIs9 = 0;
    int totalIs10 = 0;
    int totalIs11 = 0;
    int totalIs12 = 0;
    double  twoPercent = 0;
    double  threePercent = 0;
    double  fourPercent = 0;
    double  fivePercent = 0;
    double  sixPercent = 0;
    double  sevenPercent = 0;
    double  eightPercent = 0;
    double  ninePercent = 0;
    double  tenPercent = 0;
    double  elevenPercent = 0;
    double  twelvePercent = 0;

    //intro to program and purpose
    System.out.println("Today we are going to generate 2 random dice and tally the results of their random combined rolls");
    System.out.println("At the bottom of the results, the longest streak will also be listed");

    //variable for while loop
    boolean validInput = true;
    //declaration of scanner before try/catch
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    //test for valid input
    while (validInput){
        try {
            System.out.print(" \n" + "Please enter the number of trials you would like to be performed:");
            int numberOfRolls = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());

            //Stop from calling for anything else
            userInput.close();

            //declaring of variables for die 1 and die 2
            int die1[] = new int[numberOfRolls];
            int die2[] = new int[numberOfRolls];


            //create an array for each die roll so that they can each be saved for recalling streak
            int[] array = new int[numberOfRolls];   
            for (int i=1; i<array.length; i++ ) {
                die1[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                die2[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                total = die1[i] + die2[i];

                //streak checker
                int lastTotal = die1[i-1] + die2[i-1];          
                if (lastTotal == total) {
                    streak++;
                    if (streak > newStreak) {
                        newStreak = streak;
                    } 
                } else {
                    streak = 1;
                }

                //count total of each numbered possibility rolled
                if (total == 2) {
                    totalIs2++;
                }
                if (total == 3) {
                    totalIs3++;
                }
                if (total == 4) {
                    totalIs4++;
                }
                if (total == 5) {
                    totalIs5++;
                }
                if (total == 6) {
                    totalIs6++;
                }
                if (total == 7) {
                    totalIs7++;
                }
                if (total == 8) {
                    totalIs8++;
                } 
                if (total == 9) {
                    totalIs9++;
                }
                if (total == 10) {
                    totalIs10++;
                }
                if (total == 11) {
                    totalIs11++;
                }
                if (total == 12) {
                    totalIs12++;

                    //calculate percent of each number rolled
                    twoPercent = (totalIs2 / numberOfRolls);
                    threePercent = (totalIs3 / numberOfRolls);
                    fourPercent = (totalIs4 / numberOfRolls);
                    fivePercent = (totalIs5 / numberOfRolls);
                    sixPercent = (totalIs6 / numberOfRolls);
                    sevenPercent = (totalIs7 / numberOfRolls);
                    eightPercent = (totalIs8 / numberOfRolls);
                    ninePercent = (totalIs9 / numberOfRolls);
                    tenPercent = (totalIs10 / numberOfRolls);
                    elevenPercent = (totalIs11 / numberOfRolls);
                    twelvePercent = (totalIs12 / numberOfRolls);
                }
            }

            //results
            System.out.println("\n" + "Total Results:");
            System.out.println("\n" + "Total 2  happened " + totalIs2 + " times which is " + twoPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 3  happened " + totalIs3 + " times which is " + threePercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 4  happened " + totalIs4 + " times which is " + fourPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 5  happened " + totalIs5 + " times which is " + fivePercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 6  happened " + totalIs6 + " times which is " + sixPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 7  happened " + totalIs7 + " times which is " + sevenPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 8  happened " + totalIs8 + " times which is " + eightPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 9  happened " + totalIs9 + " times which is " + ninePercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 10 happened " + totalIs10 + " times which is " + tenPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 11 happened " + totalIs11 + " times which is " + elevenPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 12 happened " + totalIs12 + " times which is " + twelvePercent + "%");
            System.out.println("The longest run was a run of " + newStreak + " *number that was on a streak*" + " that began at roll" + "*where it started*");

            //stop the loop
            validInput = false;
        }

        //catch exception and call for new input
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\n" + "Your input was not a number. Please try again: ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't your for loop starting from 0?
You should store the total of the two die in the 'array' array

Comment: when you have a long streak of IF statements like that, you should consider using a switch statement for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `//calculate percent of each number rolled` calculations just before `//results`. Notice that you put it inside `if (total == 12)`. It should actually be `percents[i] = (total[i] * 100 / numberOfRolls);`

Next time you are going to write something like:

```
int totalIs2 = 0;
int totalIs3 = 0;
...
```

You should use array

and the you may write a for loop instead of linear repetitive code

---

i.e. you may replace:

```
//calculate percent of each number rolled
twoPercent = (totalIs2 / numberOfRolls);
...
```

and

```
System.out.println("\n" + "Total 2  happened " + totalIs2 + " times which is " + twoPercent + "%");
...
```

with

```
for (int i = 2; i < totalCount.length; i++) {
    double percent = totalCount[i] * 100/ numberOfRolls;
    System.out.println("\n" + "Total " + i + "  happened " + totalCount[i] + " times which is " + percent + "%");
}
```

---

Here's the whole program:

```
public class RollThoseDices {
    private int lastTotal;
    private int streak;
    private int longestStreak;
    private int startOfTheLongestStreak;

    private int[] totalCount = new int[13];

    RollThoseDices(int numberOfRolls) {
        run(numberOfRolls);
    }

    public void run(int numberOfRolls) {
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfRolls; i++ ) {
            int die1 = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
            int die2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
            int total = die1 + die2;
            totalCount[total]++;

            if (lastTotal == total) {
                streak++;
                if (streak > longestStreak) {
                    longestStreak = streak;
                    startOfTheLongestStreak = i - longestStreak;
                }
            } else {
                streak = 1;
            }
            lastTotal = total;
        }
    }

    private static int readInt(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print(" \n" + "Please enter the number of trials you would like to be performed:");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            scanner.next();
            System.out.println("\n" + "Your input was not a number. Please try again: ");
        }
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //intro to program and purpose
        System.out.println("Today we are going to generate 2 random dice and tally the results of their random combined rolls");
        System.out.println("At the bottom of the results, the longest streak will also be listed");

        // read number of rolls
        int numberOfRolls = 0;
        try(Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            numberOfRolls = readInt(userInput);
        }

        RollThoseDices results = new RollThoseDices(numberOfRolls);

        //results
        System.out.println("\n" + "Total Results:");
        System.out.println("The longest run was a run of " + results.longestStreak + " that began at roll " + results.startOfTheLongestStreak);
        for (int i = 2; i < results.totalCount.length; i++) {
            double percent = (results.totalCount[i] * 100.0) / numberOfRolls;
            System.out.println("\n" + "Total " + i + "  happened " + results.totalCount[i] + " times which is " + percent + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the first answer by lifus, use an array. Also, the streak and from which trial it is starting can be stored easily enough. Store the start as 
`start = current_trial_no - current_longest_streak`. This means your assignment of the variable goes into the part where you store the longest streak value.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean run = true ;
        int[] sum = new int[13] ;
        float[] percent = new float[13];
        int streak = 0, streakValue = 0, currentStreak = 0, streakStart = 0, trials = 0 ;
        int dice1 = 0, dice2 = 0 ;
        for(int i = 0; i < sum.length; ++i)
        {
            sum[i] = 0 ;
            percent[i] = 0.0f;
        }
        do
        {
            trials = cin.nextInt();
            int prevSum = 0 ;

            for(int t = 0; t < trials; ++t)
            {
                dice1 = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                dice2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                sum[dice1 + dice2]++ ;
                if((dice1 + dice2) == prevSum)
                {
                    ++currentStreak ;
                    streakValue = prevSum ;
                    if(currentStreak > streak)
                    {
                        streak = currentStreak ;
                        streakStart = t - streak ;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    currentStreak = 1 ;
                }
                prevSum = dice1 + dice2 ;
            }

            System.out.println("Continue ? (y/n) : ");
            run = cin.nextLine().equals("y");
        } while(run);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

        // Start from 2 - the minimum sum possible.
        for(int i = 2; i < 13; ++i)
        {
            percent[i] = (float)sum[i] / (float)trials * 100.0f ;
            System.out.println("The sum " + i + " has occurred " + df.format(percent[i]) + "% of times");
        }
        System.out.println("Longest streak of " + streakValue + " has occurred for " + streak + " times");
        System.out.println("It started at : " + streakStart);
    }

}
```

Notice the inside of the `if` condition inside the loop. [Here](http://ideone.com/AgqNBF) is a working version of the same.

Comment: I really appreciate everyone's help(Even saved that last code as a reference for later with that continue option).  Thank you guys! This is basically where I am at currently but I will probably tweak it some more in the future.  Thanks again!

Comment: 4 spaces instead of a tab to indent.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have been given the immediate advice of using Arrays. As the others have demonstrated this significantly shortens the lines of code and repetitiveness in typing things out. 
One more thing I would highlight is when programming try think more abstractly. Break the functions down to smaller easier chunks. Sometimes when thinking about the whole picture, it becomes a bit consuming and alot to deal with. What this means in practice for this dice roll for example is perhaps first make a class which represents a dice, something like;

```
public class Dice
{
    //declare values

    Public Dice()
    {
     //initialise values
    }

    public int rollDice(int times)
    {
     // some code here
    ]

    public int countStreaks()
    {
     // some code here
    }
}
```

Obviously the above code is just a quick example, but the point is the above class will provide you with all the basic dice functions you need to build the rest of your program. Your entry point can then simply just make use of this class to perform the functionality you want. 
You should find that programming in this way give a whole host of benefits, not limited to better productivity and make it easier for you when/if you ever want to come back and add functionality or expand on your original program beyond its original scope.
Put together this with what you've learned above with using Arrays and see how you get on. Once you've done that I'd recommend comparing your new code with the old to see the difference.

Hope that helps,

Regards,
V

Answer (score 0):

```
 import javax.swing.*;
```

import java.util.*;

public class RollThoseDice {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //start of method


    //variables needed for program
    int total;
    int newStreak = 1;
    int streak = 1;
    int totalIs2 = 0;
    int totalIs3 = 0;
    int totalIs4 = 0;
    int totalIs5 = 0;
    int totalIs6 = 0;
    int totalIs7 = 0;
    int totalIs8 = 0;
    int totalIs9 = 0;
    int totalIs10 = 0;
    int totalIs11 = 0;
    int totalIs12 = 0;
    double  twoPercent;
    double  threePercent;
    double  fourPercent;
    double  fivePercent;
    double  sixPercent;
    double  sevenPercent;
    double  eightPercent;
    double  ninePercent;
    double  tenPercent;
    double  elevenPercent;
    double  twelvePercent;

    //intro to program and purpose
    System.out.println("Today we are going to generate 2 random dice and tally the results of their random combined rolls");
    System.out.println("At the bottom of the results, the longest streak will also be listed");

    //variable for while loop
    boolean validInput = true;
    //declaration of scanner before try/catch
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    //test for valid input
    while (validInput){
        try {
        int numberOfRolls = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter the number of trials you would like to be performed: "));

            //Stop from calling for anything else
            userInput.close();

            //declaring of variables for die 1 and die 2
            int die1[] = new int[numberOfRolls];
            int die2[] = new int[numberOfRolls];


            //create an array for each die roll so that they can each be saved for recalling streak
            int[] array = new int[numberOfRolls];   
            for (int i=1; i<array.length; i++ ) {
                die1[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                die2[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                total = die1[i] + die2[i];

                //streak checker
                int lastTotal = die1[i-1] + die2[i-1];          
                if (lastTotal == total) {
                    streak++;
                    if (streak > newStreak) {
                        newStreak = streak;


        /*              // Find-Max variant -- rather than finding the max value, find the
                        // *index* of the max value
                        public int findMaxIndex(int[] nums) {
                          int maxIndex = 0;  // say the 0th element is the biggest
                          int maxValue = nums[0];

                          // Look at every element, starting at 1
                          for (int i=1; i<nums.length; i++) {
                            if (nums[i] > maxValue) {
                              maxIndex = i;
                              maxValue = nums[maxIndex];
                            }
                          }
                          return maxIndex;
                        }
*/                      

                    } 
                } else {
                    streak = 1;
                }

                //count total of each numbered possibility rolled
                if (total == 2) {
                    totalIs2++;
                }
                if (total == 3) {
                    totalIs3++;
                }
                if (total == 4) {
                    totalIs4++;
                }
                if (total == 5) {
                    totalIs5++;
                }
                if (total == 6) {
                    totalIs6++;
                }
                if (total == 7) {
                    totalIs7++;
                }
                if (total == 8) {
                    totalIs8++;
                } 
                if (total == 9) {
                    totalIs9++;
                }
                if (total == 10) {
                    totalIs10++;
                }
                if (total == 11) {
                    totalIs11++;
                }
                if (total == 12) {
                    totalIs12++;
                }
            }



    //Apply decimal place rounder in order to get percentages rounded to 2 places       



            //calculate percent of each number rolled
            twoPercent = (totalIs2 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            threePercent = (totalIs3 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            fourPercent = (totalIs4 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            fivePercent = (totalIs5 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            sixPercent = (totalIs6 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            sevenPercent = (totalIs7 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            eightPercent = (totalIs8 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            ninePercent = (totalIs9 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            tenPercent = (totalIs10 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            elevenPercent = (totalIs11 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;
            twelvePercent = (totalIs12 / (double) numberOfRolls) * 100;

            //results
            System.out.println("\n" + "Total Results:");
            System.out.println("\n" + "Total 2  happened " + totalIs2 + " times which is " + twoPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 3  happened " + totalIs3 + " times which is " + threePercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 4  happened " + totalIs4 + " times which is " + fourPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 5  happened " + totalIs5 + " times which is " + fivePercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 6  happened " + totalIs6 + " times which is " + sixPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 7  happened " + totalIs7 + " times which is " + sevenPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 8  happened " + totalIs8 + " times which is " + eightPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 9  happened " + totalIs9 + " times which is " + ninePercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 10 happened " + totalIs10 + " times which is " + tenPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 11 happened " + totalIs11 + " times which is " + elevenPercent + "%");
            System.out.println("Total 12 happened " + totalIs12 + " times which is " + twelvePercent + "%");
            System.out.println("The longest run was a run of " + newStreak + " *number that was on a streak*" + " that began at roll" + "*where it started*");

            //stop the loop
            validInput = false;
        }

        //catch exception and call for new input
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\n" + "Your input was not a number. Please try again: ");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*; //importing utilities

public class RollThoseDice {

```
//private variables for use in code
private int firstRoll; //initial total to compare with next to scan for streaks
private int streak; //streak
private int longestStreak; //longest streak if more than 1
private int beginningOfLongestStreak; //where in the code the longest streak started for display
private int[] combineTotal = new int[13]; //total of 2 randomly rolled 6-sided dice

RollThoseDice(int numberOfRolls) {
    run(numberOfRolls);
}

public void run(int numberOfRolls) {
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfRolls; i++ ) {
        int die1 = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1); //random number between 1-6
        int die2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        int total = die1 + die2; //math for total
        combineTotal[total]++; //adding totals to the array

        if (firstRoll == total) { //comparing 2 rolls in order to see if there is a streak or not
            streak++;
            if (streak > longestStreak) { //comparing new streak to old streak to pick the larger of 2
                longestStreak = streak;
                beginningOfLongestStreak = i - longestStreak; //getting to the beginning of the streak in order to display to user
            }
        } else {
            streak = 1;
        }
        firstRoll = total;
    }
}

private static int readInt(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.print(" \n" + "Please enter the number of trials you would like to be performed: "); //prompt user for number of trials (int only)
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        scanner.next();
        System.out.println("\n" + "Your input was not a number. Please try again: "); //drop garbage input
    }
    return scanner.nextInt(); //return good input
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //intro to program and purpose
    System.out.println("Today we are going to generate 2 random dice and tally the results of their random combined rolls");
    System.out.println("At the bottom of the results, the longest streak will also be listed");

    // read number of rolls
    int numberOfRolls = 0; //casting the number of rolls as 0 initially
    try(Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        numberOfRolls = readInt(userInput); //declaring that the above good input is variable number of rolls
    }

    RollThoseDice results = new RollThoseDice(numberOfRolls);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00"); //round the decimal values

    //results
    System.out.println("\n" + "Total Results:");
    for (int i = 2; i < results.combineTotal.length; i++) {
        double percent = (results.combineTotal[i] * 100.0) / numberOfRolls;
        System.out.println("Total " + i + "  happened " + results.combineTotal[i] + " times which is " + df.format(percent) + "%"); //display rolls info
}
    System.out.println("\n" +"The longest run was a run of " + results.longestStreak + " that began at roll " + results.beginningOfLongestStreak); //display streak info
}
```

}